# Glassfish V4 admin password

Tags: java, ubuntu, glassfish, admin

Help!  I have tried everything.  I cannot log into the glassfish admin console on ec2.  I want to enable the admin console at 4848 but ./asadmin keeps asking me for a password.  I have tried admin/adminadmin anonymous/adminadmin changeit/adminadmin changeit/admin.

What in god's name is this out of the box install?  Running ubuntu!

Comment: This might be more appropriate on a different site? Also this is hardly a java question. The only relation to java is that glassfish is written in java and is a javaee server. But the password management has nothing todo with java.

Comment: Not helpful?  Any idea how to fix instead of criticize the question?

Comment: I already told you: Ask the ubuntu guys. Remove the java tag. Give us at least the concrete command you use and the output.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to actually set the admin password. Do do that you'll need ssh access to the box. By default, there is no admin password and remote administration is disabled.

Set the admin password:

```
asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 change-admin-password
```

Now you need to enable remote administration

```
asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 enable-secure-admin
```

Now you should be able to connect with your browser over port 4848. This information is in the glassfish administration guide but it's not obvious.